# Use PIVOT TABLE to show occupation percentage by month from date ranges. google sheet

Tags: pivot, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

my first time here.

I have a lease table where each row has the follow:

Lease number | Tenant name | unit number | checkin date | checkout date.

I need to have a table (prefer a PIVOT) that will show me the total occupation (by %) per month for each year. Keep in mind that the checkin-checkout dates can be from mid of one month till mid of another month (oct 3 2020 - feb 17 2021)

Expected result:

```
   | 2019 | 2020 | 2021

jan | 0% | 58% | 67%
feb | 67% | 21% | 42%
mar ....
```

as I'm not a professional sim looking for a simple/easy way to resolve it.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YHpEfBFkBFy5xMD30KyI1zcT_DJ9ykKoVoztA1jygIY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: how did you calculate 80% for december 2020? https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgkOk.png